# AutoCompleteTextView not working in application

Tags: android, dictionary, autocompletetextview

In my adroid map application I want to make a **AutocompleteVextView**

Here is my code:

```
public class AutoComplete extends MapActivity  {
private MapController mapController;
private MyLocationOverlay myLocation;
private MapView mapView;
private  AutoCompleteTextView textView;
public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private TextView mStatusView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto_complete);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(10);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myLocation = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    myLocation.enableMyLocation();
    myLocation.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mapController.animateTo(myLocation.getMyLocation());
            myLocation.getLastFix();
            mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocation);

        }
     });


//AutocompleteView  



     AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
      autoCompView.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item));

   }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        myLocation.enableMyLocation();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
        myLocation.disableMyLocation();
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return true;
}

private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleApp";

private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

private static final String API_KEY = "02m46CJ1ckrhGhQPU3KjnXiR90H1Ovjg7Bum5Q";

private ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
    ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("??location=37.787930,-122.4074990" + API_KEY); 
        sb.append("?sensor=true&key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&&radius=5000");
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,jsonResults.toString() );

        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        return resultList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
        return resultList;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    try {
        // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

        // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
        resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
    }
    Log.i("List", resultList.toString());
    return resultList;
}
```

The code shown in below also a part of AutoComplete class

```
      private class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList<String> resultList;

    public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }};
        return filter;
    }
}

    }
```

This is my code its is not working in my application why?
Could you give any suggestions.. I am new to android.
Thanks..

Comment: i think this link is helpfull for you...http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-add-autocompletion-to-an-edittext

Comment: May be this will help you:  http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/example-of-autocompletetextview.html